# How to mock a many-to-many relationship in Laravel unit tests

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following tables, users, roles and role_user which creates the many-to-many relationship.

In my UserFactory when creating users I assign them the basic role of 'user' like so:

```
$factory->afterCreating(User::class, function ($user, $faker){
    $roles = Role::where('name', 'user')->get();
    $user->roles()->sync($roles->pluck('id')->toArray());
});
```

And then in my unit test I can test for users that they are redirected with a 302 when trying to access admin pages:

```
$this->actingAs(factory(\App\User::class)->make());

$request = Request::create('/admin', 'GET');

$middleware = new AccessAdmin;
$response = $middleware->handle($request, function () {});

$this->assertEquals($response->getStatusCode(), 302);
```

This works as expected but the problem is testing the reverse of this with an admin user as I'm unsure how to mock the relational data. I have tried creating the user and then attaching the roles like so:

```
$user = factory(\App\User::class)->make();
$roles = Role::where('name', 'admin')->get();
$user->roles()->sync($roles->pluck('id')->toArray());
```

This gives me the following error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048
>   Column 'user_id' cannot be null

This is correct because the user is never created in the DB so the user has no ID.

How do I mock the user/role relationship?

Comment: Can you post your `User` model? Have you defined `roles` as a `belongsToMany` relationship? If so it should be looking for a foreign key like `role_user_role_id_foreign`

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want to mock the relationship? 
Instead, I would recommend recommend using DatabaseTransactions trait in your Test file, and create() method instead of make() for your factory.

```
use DatabaseTransactions;

....

$user = factory(\App\User::class)->create();
```

Comment: I didn't know about the transaction trait. Will that rollback changes after the test has run?

Comment: Yes. Side effect is increasing auto increment value in table. But in most cases it won't matter.

Comment: do you know what package this trait is under? I need to bring it into my tests because it's not found `PHP Fatal error:  Trait 'Tests\Unit\DatabaseTransactions' not found in`

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/DatabaseTransactions.html

Comment: dude that is what I did at the end, but why can't we mock it? why can't we make dummy instances which are not persisted in db? I did that with all other relations except many to many, couldn't find a solution yet